# Is it highlighted a synonym of stood out?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality-in-context, synonyms

I can't use **stood out** here so I used **highlighted**. I haven't found good synonyms without the word "stood", I really appreciate suggestions without this word.

.In the subjects I directed, she **highlighted** for her capacity to innovate and a characteristic curiosity to explore beyond the instruction.

Comment: No, it isn't. Something that **stands out** is easily noticeable (like a shape literally 'standing out' from a flat surface). If you **highlight** something, you do something to _make_ it noticeable (like shining a light on it). You could say she **was conspicuous** or **was notable**.

Comment: In addition perhaps _she shone_ would work although perhaps slightly informal.

Comment: I decided to rewrite it this way, but I am not sure if the meaning is preserved? : *In the subjects I taught her, her capacity to innovate and a characteristic curiosity to explore beyond the instruction often called my attention.*.